# Is it ok to have multiple code-behinds in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, code-behind

I have a page that contains a large number of hierarchical grids. Currently using ADO.NET for data access so it can take up a lot of lines and be a little confusing when looking for things. I discovered that I could use multiple partial classes with the same name to make more than one code-behind for this page so I could easily find what part of the grid I was looking for just by clicking the right .razor.cs file. I haven't seen much talk on this online so I was wondering what you guys thought about this. It has really helped me find the parts of the code I need quickly but I'm pretty sure it's not exactly standard practice or how things are meant to be.

TLDR: Found out I could make multiple code-behinds, couldn't find much online about it, wondering how people feel about them.

Comment: Don't see why not. I use multiple Partials on certain data service classes to separate out functionality/Interface implementations.  See what anyone else says.

Comment: It works but the separation it gives you is only partial too. Everything will still be in one big namespace. Consider using services instead.